# SQL Select Statement with DateDiff SUM and Math operation

Tags: sql-server, datediff

Having Table columns as below

```
Employee Id StartDate    EndDate
1           2014-07-01   2014-07-10
1           2014-07-11   2014-07-15
1           2014-07-16   2014-07-17
2           2014-07-18   2014-07-30
```

In the above data, I want to Sum of the whole date period for an employee and take the % of the contribution of the of the date as another column

```
SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate)), 
        DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) / SUM(DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate)) 
FROM dbo.[abovetable] 
WHERE EmployeedId=1
```

Here, total days for employee id 1 is 17 (10 + 5 + 2). there are 3 records under him. for the first record,
current row days difference / todaydays should be the result.
i.e.

1. 10/17
2. 5/17
3. 2/17

Should be the result. Any combination will work out with group by?

Comment: Are you encountering an error message or just incorrect results?  what results are you getting or what error message with the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of scope / order of operation. The aggregate sum is not available at the time you want to do the % calculation.  So you first have to generate the sum and then you can get the %.

This can be accomplished with a COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION (CTE) or a sub query.

Here's the CTE Example.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT EMPLOYEEID, SUM(DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate)) as SumDates, 
FROM dbo.[abovetable] 
GROUP BY EmployeeID)
SELECT EmployeeID, SumDates, DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) / SumDates
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN CTE on E.EmployeeID = CTE.EmployeeID
WHERE EmployeedId=1
```

and here's an inline query (sub query) example

```
SELECT EmployeeID, SumDates, DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) / SumDates
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID, SUM(DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate)) AS SumDates, 
            FROM dbo.[abovetable] 
            GROUP BY EmployeeID) CTE 
 ON E.EmployeeID = CTE.EmployeeID
WHERE EmployeedId=1
```

In both cases the sum of the dates is being determined before the division is occurring.  In the CTE example, the CTE is materialized with data before the math.

In the case of the inline query, the order of operations is inside out so it calculates the sub table, then executes the query.